# Trying to remove a nested object in mongoose

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongoose

I'm trying to remove a nested object, but for some reason I'm doing something wrong as it seems that I cant access the nested object. I can delete objects that aren't nested.

Here is my code

Json:

```
{
   "_id": ObjectId("55904d2da35bf71c06184f60"),
   "title": "h1",
   "url": "h1",
   "menuIndex": NumberInt(0),
   "date": ISODate("2015-06-28T21:12:38.256Z"),
   "contents": [
     {
       "order": NumberInt(0),
       "data": "something",
       "_id": ObjectId("55904d38a35bf71c06184f62") 
    },
     {
       "order": NumberInt(1),
       "data": "not something",
       "_id": ObjectId("55904d49a35bf71c06184f63") 
    }
  ],
   "__v": NumberInt(0) 
}
```

Api:

```
router.post('/content/delete/:id/:contentId', sessionCheck, function(req,res) {
    var id = req.body._id;
    var contentId = req.body._id;
    Page.update({
        _id: id
    }, {
        $pull: {'contents': {
            _id: contentId            
        }}},
        function(err){
            if(err)
                return res.send(err);
        }
    );
});
```

Factory:

```
.factory('pagesFactory', ['$http', 
  function($http) {

    return {   
       deleteContent: function(id,contentId) {          
          return $http.post('/api/content/delete/'+ id + '/' + contentId);
       }

    };
  }
])
```

Controller:

```
$scope.deleteContent = function(id,contentId) {
    pagesFactory.deleteContent(id,contentId);
};
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="data in pageContent.contents track by data.order">
    <button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="deleteContent(pageContent._id,data._id)">Delete</button>
    <div ng-bind-html="trustAsHtml((data.data))">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is your function to remove the nested object?

Comment: If I understand this correctly, are you trying to remove the key value of contents?

Comment: yes exactly.But not all just the ones that match the contentId.And the function is in my Factory.

Comment: should be req.params.id and req.params.contentId

Comment: im gonna try it but i can get both ids just fine with req.body._id.

Comment: nope still the same thing.The weird thing is that i can get both ids just fine its just dont delete the object.

Comment: If that is the case, I think it is a bug on the server side then? Since you successfully made the delete request with correct id

Comment: maybe you are right but i just thought it maybe a problem with ng-repeat i will try to delete from the controller and from inside the api and see if that works.

Comment: nope you are right its a problem from server from some reason even if i try to manually put the ids and make the post still nothing,and i also dont get any error i get status 200.

Comment: ok @hassansin was right i thought i tried ir but it typed param and not params.so im waiting to write the answer so i can accept it.

Comment: All right! I am answering then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `id` and `contentId` are sent as url params not POST body. So the correct code is:

```
var id = req.params.id; // not req.body._id
var contentId = req.params.contentId; // not req.body._id
Page.update({
    _id: id
}, {
    $pull: {'contents': {
        _id: contentId            
    }}},
    function(err){
        if(err)
            return res.send(err);
    }
);
```